# Extra Padding while sending a ethernet packet?

Tags: c, sockets, memcpy, ethernet, packets

I was writing a code to send a packet to the other mac Address. I ma using a struct to create a packet as mentioned below:

```
typedef struct vlink_prm_in_s
{
vlink_header_t  header;
uint32_t        address;
uint16_t        length;
}vlink_prm_in_t;
```

and when I want to send a packet I do following steps:

```
  vlink_prm_in_t g_pkt;
  g_pkt.header.verCmd = 0x43;
  g_pkt.header.reverseVerCmd = ~(g_pkt.header.verCmd);
  g_pkt.address = 0x11111111;
  g_pkt.length = 0x2222;
  memcpy(sendbuf+headerLen, &g_pkt, sizeof(g_pkt));
  printf("%x\n", sendbuf[headerLen+4] );
  payloadLen = sizeof(g_pkt);
  sendbuf[headerLen+payloadLen] = 0xA5;
  payloadLen++;
```

when I send the packet I get the following packet when I track it in WireShark:

aa bb cc dd ee 66 98 ee cb 03 be 1d ea e8 43 bc **00 00** 11 11 11 11 22 22 **00 00** a5

I don't know where do I get those extra zeros(highlighted) from ? Thanks.

Comment: For a starter: Don't do this. Properly marshal the fields to a `uint8_t` array.  For the rest: No [mcve], no information. Read [ask]. And that does not look like an Ethernet packet; MAC addresses are 48 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking on internet more I found out that struct should be purely increasing or decreasing order (or all the variables should be same size). This way you can remove the extra zeros. So I did as follows:

```
typedef struct vlink_prm_in_s
{
vlink_header_t  header;
uint16_t        address1;
uint16_t        address2;
uint16_t        length;
}vlink_prm_in_t;
```

This fixed my problem.